# using win32 in native applications

Tags: c++, win32gui

Is it necessary to use win32 in full native applications or it's good to use the visual mode of VC++ Express instead.

I want to know about the big programs like game engines that, are they using win32 to present their set of tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win32 API is basically a set of procedures to work with low level Windows objects like windows, controls, sockets and so on. So, if you say "native" that means that the only way you can do anything is using Win32 API.

Game engines are quite primitive from low level standpoint. Game engines are mostly algorithms, abstractions like polygons (instead of low level triangles), textures and others of that kind. From Windows standpoint, it's just like "create window", "initialize OpenGL" and that's all. All the other stuff is mostly not related to Windows, but quite cross-platform. For instance, OpenGL is not related with any particular platform like Windows, Linux or Mac OS, OpenGL is always the same. The only thing that differs is how you create the Window and initialize OpenGL.

Comment: I know that. I making game for 7 years with different engines. Because I want to start writing a 2d game engine with SFML, thought that I should obtain some information about starting.

Comment: If you've been doing it for 7 years, you should probably know that all the more or less good game engines are cross-platform, they do all this low level stuff for you, so you can just concentrate on what you really do. I'm a Windows programmer for 10 years and believe, if you can do without Win32 API, do it without Win32 API. It's obsolete for 'real' development. For instance, if you just want to have an empty window, the purely native implementation is about 50 lines of code.

Comment: @loki2302: You sure do have an unusual definition for "real" development. Especially since it is *the* API for the Windows operating system and every Windows application has to interact with the Windows API at some point. Yes you need a bit of code to make windows but as you said it's low level and you would wrap it in a framework or library of some sort.

Comment: @In_silico: real development is when you solve business problems using programming. And that's all. That's why someone pays you. Not because you know how Windows works, but because you solve problems. When you have to spend 4 hours just to get an empty window, it's more to hacking than to development.

Comment: @loki2302: You know, when you coming through the game making, after several years you'll be realize that you should make your steps constant to stay in this industry. So for that I should make my own engine. Totally I wanted to know what makes game engines to use native while they can use visuals. Of course you're right but If you say being native on different platforms like Windows, iOS ... It's true On different consoles PS3, XBOX 360 ... they just need their exact SDK to compile like that system and next run on that platform. Thanks anyway for your advises.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, "Win32" and "native code" are basically the same thing. If you're using .NET to build your interface, it's not native code. You can, of course, write code that mixes native and .NET components.

Big-budget games are typically written in native code to ease porting, as they will have to run on Windows, Xbox 360, PS3, and possibly Wii or Mac. I'm sure there are exceptions, but I'm not aware of any major software that runs on multiple platforms and is written entirely with managed code.

Comment: Please expand on why you believe writing 'Native Code' eases porting. I would disagree. I would think the reason games do this is only for performance.

Comment: Because (almost) every platform has C++, while you're not going to get very far writing a game for Nintendo 3DS in C#. That's all I meant.